# Spring Boot and Angular Application running on separate docker containers access same port 443?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, docker, containers

I'm running my angular app and my spring boot app on different docker containers ON the same server. The angular app is running on port 443 and I recently configured my spring boot application to support https requests, this means that the spring boot app has to run on port 443 too.

This creates a problem because both docker containers are trying to run on the same port. 
How do I implement this in a way that the spring boot app running on docker container supports HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a proxy server to route to your docker containers based on path. Check out nginx, this could give a better idea

> https://medium.com/@tiangolo/angular-in-docker-with-nginx-supporting-environments-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-bb9f1724e984